# Remote desktop - log-on as the same user remotely

Tags: windows-7, windows, remote-desktop, remote-connection

Imagine this use-case.

I have PC at my workplace and a notebook I can carry home. After my working hours, I lock the session and go home. Then at home, I want to be able to connect to the PC remotely, from home from the notebook, to the current session on the PC as the same user as is logged in so that I can access all opened programs as I left them once I left work. The next day, I want to come back to work, "unlock" my PC at workplace and carry on from the point I disconnected via remote session.

Is it possible with Remote Desktop? If not, how else?

Both machines run Windows 7 Enterprise, 64-bit.

Comment: This is indeed possible.  When you logged into the computer it will actually appear to be locked.  You then simply at that point disconnect from the remote desktop session and unlock the computer.  I do this between two Windows 7 machines daily.

Comment: Thanks, that is true. "Unlocking" really kicks me out of the remote session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the remote desktop client with the `/admin` parameter, e.g. `mstsc /admin`. This will force the client to connect to the console session in stead of starting a new session. Though this should only have to be done for true Terminal Server connections, the default windows desktop client should already connect to the console (logged on) user.

In other words, it should do so automatically. The /admin option exists for terminal server purposes.

Comment: Correct. It will do automatically. My problem was elsewhere - I needed to ALLOW remote desktop connection on target machine, that's why I thought I need to be logged of on target machine (because an error message was showing up). Thanks.